# Bash script to delete comment lines where no code exists within a C code file?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

the code is like this:

```
/* a comment line in a C program */
printf("It is /* NOT a comment line */\n");
x = 5; /* This is an assignment, not a comment line */
[TAB][SPACE] /* another empty comment line here */
```

And the expected output is like this:

```
printf("It is /* NOT a comment line */\n");
x = 5; /* This is an assignment, not a comment line */
```

Comment: You have mentioned: `x = 5; /* This is an assignment, not a comment line */`. In `c` everything, and I mean really everything, that looks like `/* some text anywhere in the code */` is a comment and nothing else than a comment. Or do you just want to delete comments in those lines no code exists?

Answer (score 1):

To remove the line and print the output to standard out:

```
sed '/pattern to match/d' ./infile
```

To directly modify the file (and create a backup):

```
sed -i.bak '/pattern to match/d' ./infile
```

Comment: And what is the pattern
And i tried this:
$ sed '/^\/\//d;/^\/\*$/,/^\*\//d' infile.cpp